# CSS flex has problems with the layout

Tags: css, reactjs

[image: Flex wrap not working]

```
<div className="product">
        <h2>Top Products</h2>
        <div className="container">
            {
                products.map((item,index) => (
                    <>
                    <div className="box" key={index}>
                        <div className="img_box">
                            <img src={item.Img} alt={item.Title} />
                            <div className="icon">
                                <li><AiOutlineShoppingCart /></li>
                                <li><BsEye /></li>
                                <li><AiOutlineHeart  className="heart"/></li>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="detail">
                            <p>{item.Cat}</p>
                            <h3>{item.Title}</h3>
                            <h4>${item.Price}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.product{
padding: 30px 50px;
width: 100%;
}
.product h2{
font-size: 32px;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.product .container{
/* text-align: center; */
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
gap: 30px;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.product .container .box
{
padding: 10px 20px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 300px;
height: 430px;
border: 1px solid #e2e0e0;
margin-bottom: 20px;
transition: 0.5s;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 5px;
}
.product .container .box:hover
{
 box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
}
.product .container .box .img_box img
{
width: 280px;
height: 250px;
/* margin-right: 110px; */
}

.product .container .box .img_box .icon
{
left: 22%;
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
right: 0;
display: flex;
gap: 30px;
font-size: 22px;
list-style-type: none;
/* flex-direction: column; */
/* margin-top: 20px; */
transition: 0.5s;
}

.heart{
color: red;
}

.product .container .box .detail
{
margin-top: 10px;
}
.product .container .box .detail p
{
color: #9a9a9a;
font-size: 14px;
}
.product .container .box .detail h3
{
font-size: 16px;
margin-top: 5px;
color: #010f1c;
transition: 0.5s;
}
.product .container .box:hover .detail h3
{
color: #0989ff;
}
.product .container .box .detail h4
{
margin-top: 5px;
font-size: 14px;
color: #0989ff;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

From the image, I would like to put the last item on the second row below the second item of the first row. In CSS, even I used `flex-wrap: wrap` and `justify-content: space-between` the last item only put aside. I am not sure why `flex-wrap` is not working to wrap the items Any solutions can move the last item below the second item of the first row if I am using `display:flex`?

Comment: Any reason for not using grid? And please include the code you already have which makes it much easier to create a relevant answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You should add `margin-right: auto;` on your last item :

```css
.container > .box:last-of-type {
    margin-right: auto
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can achieve this with flex, at least not as long as the white-space needs to be dynamic in size. If not, you could remove `justify-content` all together and use `grid-gap:20px;`.